# I need help C# and Emgu cv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am developing a simple application on face recognition using EmguCv and c#. i am using ms access data to store sample data base. whenever in compile the code i get error ***"OpenCV: Different sizes of objects"*** Here is my code.... thanks in ADVANCE.

```
public partial class Facerecognition : Form
{
    EigenObjectRecognizer Recognizer;
    private Capture cam;
    Image<Bgr, Byte> frame;
    Image<Gray, Byte> frame2;
    private HaarCascade Haar;
    MCvFont font = new MCvFont(FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5d, 0.5d);

    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataAdapter Adapter;
    DataTable Table = new DataTable();

    List<string> FaceName = new List<string>();
    List<Image<Gray, byte>> FaceImg = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
    int ConTrain;
    string name;
    Image result;

    public Facerecognition()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Haar = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        ConnectDatabase();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Traningset t = new Traningset();
        t.Show();
    }

    public void Process(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frame = cam.QueryFrame();
        LoadRecognizer();
        pictureBox1.Image = frame.ToBitmap();
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cam = new Capture();
        Application.Idle += Process;
    }

    /*public void FaceDetection()
    {
        frame2 = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        var faces = frame.DetectHaarCascade(Haar, 1.2, 3, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(25, 25))[0];

        foreach (var face in faces)
        {
            frame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(Color.Black), 3);
            // MessageBox.Show("Face detected " + faces.Length.ToString());
        }

    }*/

    public void ConnectDatabase()
    {
        Connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=facedatabase.mdb.mdb";
        Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select facename, faceimg from traningset", Connection);
        OleDbCommandBuilder CommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(Adapter);
        Adapter.Fill(Table);
        Connection.Open();
        if (Table.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            int numofrows = Table.Rows.Count;
        }
        Connection.Close();
    }

    public Image GetFaceFromDB()
    {
            Image Fetehedimg;
            byte[] fetechedimgbytes = (byte[])Table.Rows[0]["faceimg"];
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fetechedimgbytes);
            Fetehedimg = Image.FromStream(stream);
            return Fetehedimg;
    }
    public void LoadRecognizer()
    {
        /////////////////////////////////////////////// FACE DETECTER /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        frame2 = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        var faces = frame.DetectHaarCascade(Haar, 1.2, 3, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(25, 25))[0];

        foreach (var face in faces)
        {
            frame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(Color.Black), 3);
            // MessageBox.Show("Face detected " + faces.Length.ToString());
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        ConnectDatabase();
        Bitmap bitimage;
        Image img;
        img = new Bitmap(100, 100);
        int numofrows=0;
        if(Table.Rows.Count!=0)
        {
             numofrows=Table.Rows.Count;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numofrows; i++)
        {
            byte[] fetchedBytes = (byte[])Table.Rows[i]["faceimg"];
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fetchedBytes);
            bitimage = new Bitmap(stream);
            //bitimage = bitimage.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
            FaceImg.Add(new Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, Byte>(bitimage));

            String faceName = (String)Table.Rows[i]["facename"];
            FaceName.Add(faceName);
        }
        if (FaceImg.ToArray().Length != 0)
        {

            MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(4, 0.001);

            Recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
                FaceImg.ToArray(),
                FaceName.ToArray(),
                3000,
                ref termCrit);

           MessageBox.Show("face recognized");
           // frame.Draw(name, ref font, new Point(faces.rect.X - 2, faces.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.LightGreen));
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Could you say which line gives the error?

Comment: `code` Recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer (FaceImg.ToArray(), FaceName.ToArray(), 3000, ref termCrit);     @Berriel

Comment: You commented a line with `resize`, so `facesImg` contains images of different sizes? If so, uncomment this line...

Comment: but `resize` line give error

Comment: And i think the error is because of different size of picture in traning set.....any idea how to do it....

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment `Resize`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numofrows; i++)
{
    byte[] fetchedBytes = (byte[])Table.Rows[i]["faceimg"];
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fetchedBytes);
    bitimage = new Bitmap(stream);
    Image<Gray, byte> img = new Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, Byte>(bitimage )
    Image<Gray, byte> resizedImage = img.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
    FaceImg.Add(resizedImage);

    String faceName = (String)Table.Rows[i]["facename"];
    FaceName.Add(faceName);
}
```

You can't perform in `Resize` in place, that's why the uncommented line was giving you another error:

```
// not allowed
bitimage = bitimage.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
```

Comment: Error 10 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' does not contain a definition for 'Resize' and no extension method 'Resize' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\automated attendance\automated attendance\Facerecognition.cs 131 59 automated attendance

Comment: Ohh, I see. `bitimage` was a `Bitmap`. Updated the code. Try again, please.